# Getting keyboard input with TextField

Tags: flutter, dart, text, keyboard, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to build a custom rich text editor. I've decided to approach this by using a text widget to display text and gather keyboard input myself (instead of using a `TextField`).

On desktop platforms, I can use the `KeyboardListener` to reliably get keyboard input. However, on mobile platforms, the software keyboard won't show up unless I use a `TextField`. I do not want to use a `TextField`. How can I reliably open the software keyboard and keep it open while other actions such as selecting things are happening?

I am aware of `SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod("TextInput.show");` but this doesn't seem to work when you don't have any `TextField`s.

Thanks!